# removing script element and it's actions/events  from page

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a script element in my web which is not in my header ( i don't know if thats important )

script.js

```
 $(function(){
    $('.test').click(function(){
      alert(' this button was clicked ! ');
    })
 })
```

i need it to be removed from my page

```
var script = $('script[src$="js/script.js"]') ;
if(sript.length == 0 )
{
  alert(" script cannot be found  ");
}
else
{
  script.remove();
  alert(" done ! ");
}
```

but after this still i can see the script in my source code and when i click the button still i get the message

**i don't want to unbind the click event for that button . it's just an example i want the script and all of it's events gone**

Comment: removing the script element would not undo all the actions taken within it - meaning it wouldn't automatically remove the click handlers on `.test`

Comment: @mattb thanx apparently it doesn't work like i thought

Answer (score 2):

You just need to unbind the event handler like:

```
$('.test').off('click')
```

If you have several handlers for `click` attached - then you need to use `namespaces` to have more fine grained control over binding/unbinding